# SyntaxError: Unexpected token at Object.parse AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In my **AngularJS** application, when I trying to get **data with new line** from database, I get the following error :

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
at Object.parse (native)
at Object.oc [as fromJson] (http://localhost:8080/pjib/js/angular.min.js:14:156)
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/pjib/admin_pbjib/news/index.php:191:34)
at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:8080/pjib/js/angular.min.js:37:96)
at $get.z.instance (http://localhost:8080/pjib/js/angular.min.js:76:210)
at http://localhost:8080/pjib/js/angular.min.js:59:164
at s (http://localhost:8080/pjib/js/angular.min.js:7:408)
at v (http://localhost:8080/pjib/js/angular.min.js:59:148)
at g (http://localhost:8080/pjib/js/angular.min.js:52:9)
at g (http://localhost:8080/pjib/js/angular.min.js:52:26)
```

My code **(php)**:

```
 $getData = json_encode(GetAllDataFromServer($table_name));
```

JSON encoded output string :

```
 [  
   {  
      "news_id":"1",
      "heading":"In purto percipit ......t",
      "news_body":"In purto percipit nam, .........",
      "news_img":"",
      "create_date":"2015-02-21",
      "display_status":"Yes"
  },
  {  
      "news_id":"2",
      "heading":"Habemus adipisci ....",
       "news_body":"In .... some string .... reque choro.\r\n \r\nHabemus adipisci .... some string .... dissentiunt.\r\n \r\nVel aliquid .... some string ....  disputando te cum.\r\n \r\nIn usu .......",
      "news_img":"",
      "create_date":"2015-02-21",
      "display_status":"No"
   }
]
```

My AngularJS code :

```
 // only problem when '\r\n' appear in the json object(table column)
 $scope.news = angular.fromJson('<?=$getData ?>');
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem using the following code :

php code :

```
$getData = json_encode(GetAllDataFromServer($table_name));
```

After encoding db info into json fotmat, just do the following code.

AngularJS/JavaScript Code :

```
scope.news = <?=$getData ?>;
```

Comment: In other words, you do not need to parse it twice.